# Dynamically changing ImageStatic in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a map with one ImageLayer, with its source an ImageStatic. My page first loads the map with one image. Once a user presses a button, I want the ImageStatic to change to another predefined image (with the change reflected on the map). How can I accomplish this in OpenLayers?

Comment: you need to update the source

Comment: If you define two sources you can update the layer https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/lazy-source.html

Comment: I was hoping to be able to trigger a rerender and reuse the existing source, but that should also work. Thanks!